# What's wrong with my recursion implementation?

Tags: python, recursion

I have recently started learning programming, just completed a course on edX. I was trying to solve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6eEo.png) problem on HackerRank and it is running out of time in each case. What am I doing wrong?

```
n,k = input().strip().split(' ')
n,k = [int(n),int(k)]
x = [int(x_temp) for x_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
x.sort()
def transmitter(aList=[], target=0):
    '''
    accepts a list of house location, and a target location for the transmitter
    returns the optimal number of transmitters required to cover all the  houses
    '''
    List = aList[:]
    start = target - k
    end = target + k + 1

    for i in range(start, end):
        if i in List:
            List.remove(i)
    if not List:
        return 1
    m = max(List)
    for e in List:
        if transmitter(List, e) < m:
            m = transmitter(List, e)

    return 1 + m

m = max(x)
for e in x:
    if transmitter(x, e) < m:
        m = transmitter(x, e)

print(m)
```

I am pretty new to this. Sorry for making any obvious mistakes, or for posting this here in case this is not the suitable site. In that case, it will be really helpful if you can recommend a site where I can ask such question.

[the screenshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6eEo.png)

Comment: time (cf your question) and space (cf your title) are two different dimensions (without wanting to enter into the time-space continuum debate).

Comment: @trincot but I thought I was running out of time because my solution was too memory expensive.

Comment: I could not find the description of the problem. It seems the URL is no longer valid. Could you add the description?

Comment: What happens if you store the result of your recursive calls instead of calling them twice (once in the `if` condition and once if the condition is true)? So something like: `result = transmitter(List, e)` and then just `if result < m: m = result`

Comment: Without knowing the original challenge, I guess the algorithm is wrong: values are used as indices and vice versa, which could be intended, but then it is really strange that the array is sorted at the start.

Comment: @trincot  
Included a screenshot of the problem

Comment: looking at it now...

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but it's a very bad idea to use a list as a default value for an argument. The default will be shared by all calls to the function. You're not actually using the default value for `aList` anywhere, and indeed it never would make sense to do so. You should probably just remove the default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure a greedy algorithm solves this problem optimally in just `O(N)` time. There's not need for any recursion. Just place each transmitter in turn as far to the right as you can without leaving any houses to its left uncovered. Stop when the last house is covered.

Here's how I'd code that:

```
def hackerland(houses, k):  # houses should be sorted list of locations
    first = None  # location of first uncovered house
    last = 0      # last location covered by a previous transmitter
    prev = None
    count = 0  # transmitters = []

    for x in houses:
        if first is not None and x > first + k:
            first = None
            count += 1  # transmitters.append(prev)
            last = prev + k

        if last is not None and x > last:
            last = None
            first = x

        prev = x

    if first is not None:
        count += 1  # transmitters.append(prev)

    return count  # return transmitters
```

I've included comments that show how this code could be easily modified to return a list of the transmitter locations, rather than just a count of how many are needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to take a recursive approach. In fact, you can just work forward, iterate over the houses, placing transmitters when the previously placed one does not reach far enough to cover the current house, etc.

It is a bit more complicated than that, but not much. See this code:

```
# input
n,k = input().strip().split(' ')
n,k = [int(n),int(k)]
x = [int(x_temp) for x_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]

# eliminate duplicate house x-xoordinates, they don't influence the result
houses = list(set(x))
houses.sort()
# add extreme far dummy house (will make the loop easier)
houses.append(100000) 
reachedX = 0 # coordinate until where the previously placed transmitter reaches
unreachedX = -1 # coordinate that the next one needs to cover (to the left)
lastHouseId = -1 # index where previous transmitter was placed
transmitters = [] # coordinates of the placed transmitters
for houseId, houseX in enumerate(houses):
    if reachedX > unreachedX: # we might still be in range of last transmitter
        if houseX > reachedX: # we just went out of reach
            unreachedX = houseX # this house must be covered by next one
    elif houseX - k > unreachedX: # transmitter here wouldn't reach far enough back
        lastHouseId = houseId - 1 # place it on previous house
        reachedX = houses[lastHouseId] + k
        transmitters.append(houses[lastHouseId])

print(transmitters)
print(len(transmitters))
```